# Drop shadow in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to create just a transparent shadow to use in a website. While saving as `PNG`, the shadow is saving with the solid white border. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please screenshot how you are saving the file and add it to your question so we can try to figure out whats not working correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Save for Web use PNG24 not PNG8.

Comment: And check the "Transparency" box!